# Count of non-empty cells in a column of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I want to know how many cells in a column of a `DataGridView` have values (are not empty)

Something like that:

```
datagridview1.Columns[0].Rows.NoEmpty.Count
```

Thanks!

Comment: All columns have the same rows count :)

Comment: So what problems are you experiencing?

Comment: oppss, i mean cells which contain something value

Comment: @GaboO Loop through the cells and check if they are not empty

Comment: @GaboO Do you have a datasource `List<T>` or `DataTable` or add data directly to `DataGridView`?

Comment: @Sybren Thank, i did it with loop

Answer (score 2):

While it's better to perform such query against your data source (for example your list of data), but if you want to do this with the `DataGridView` you can use such query:

```
var count = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(row => !(row.Cells[0].Value == null || row.Cells[0].Value == DBNull.Value)) 
    .Count();
```

If you are using a `DataTable` as data source, you can perform such query with your data table and then you should consider `DBNull.Value` too.

Remember to add `using System.Linq;`